# Prevent fonts and sizes to change on deployment in Qt/Felgo

Tags: android, qt, testing, fonts, felgo

I recently distributed my app made with Felgo (and Qt) to Android using Microsoft App Store. Until now, I have been testing using a Felgo live client. However, though everything else works, one big thing I noticed is that all the fonts and font sizes where completely messed up. I believe this is because it is using Android native fonts instead of what I set in my code.

Is there any way I can fix this so that all my fonts are the same as what I tested with the live client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts in Felgo should use the `sp()` method for scaling correctly, also the fontSize property *should not* be set with `sp` or `dp` scaling, since it's already scaled internally using the sp method, so it's unit is device-independent. This should preserve your font sizes across different platforms.

```
AppText {
  fontSize: 18 //same as font.pixelSize: sp(18)
}
```